# Have a total number and add equal lines

Tags: r

In a dataframe I have to columns with this:

```
expression,number
something 1,4
something 2,2
```

How is it possible to use the number of the second column and create a new df which like have rows based on number of the second column. Example of output

```
expression
something 1
something 1
something 1
something 1
something 2
something 2
```

Comment: With `e`being your dataframe: `data.frame(expression=rep(e$expression,e$number))`

Comment: @Tensibai million thanks. It works perfect.